# Obtener el id de un elemento HTML a partir de su clase con Javascript

Tags: javascript, clase, id

Tengo una lista de elementos (li) con distinto id cada uno respectivamente, pero con el mismo nombre de clase para todos. Lo que deseo es que al dar click en un elemento de la lista capture su id correspondiente usando Javascript. Hasta ahora no he podido conseguirlo.

```
 <ul>
    <li id="1" class="opciones"></li>
    <li id="2" class="opciones"></li>
    <li id="3" class="opciones"></li>
</ul>
```

Mi código en JS que no me funciona correctamente:

```
document.addEventListener('click', ev => { 
  if(ev.target.matches('.opciones')){ 
    document.querySelectorAll(".opciones").forEach(el => { 
       el.addEventListener("click", e => { 
          console.log(el.id); 
       } 
    }) 
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la delegación de eventos así, de modo que solo agregas un listener al ancestro común de los `<li>` y obtienes el elemento real que ha sido clickeado con e.target

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('ul')

ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const li = e.target
  if(li.matches('.icon-plus-circled')) {
    console.log('it match! element id: ' + li.id)
  }
  else console.log("it doesn't match")
})
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
  <li id="1" class="opciones">opcion1</li>
  <li id="2" class="opciones icon-plus-circled">opcion2</li>
  <li id="3" class="opciones">opcion3</li>
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</ul>
```

Comment: El problema es que estoy usando Delegación de Eventos porque es una lista dinámica que carga luego de hacer click en un botón. Entonces, tengo esto: 
          
    document.addEventListener('click', ev => {

        if(ev.target.matches('.opciones')){

        }
   })

Al agregar otro addEventListener como me indicaste en tu código:

     li.addEventListener('click', () => {
       console.log(li.getAttribute('id'))
     })

ahi comienza a fallar y no ejecuta correctamente el evento :(

Comment: En ese caso, estas obteniendo perfectamente el elemento clickeado, que te impide imprimir su id? agrega mas codigo o contexto porque no se cual es el problema

Comment: Si estas utilizando delegación de eventos no hace falta que agregues un evento para cada li, ahi modifique el codigo

Comment: document.addEventListener('click', ev => {

          if(ev.target.matches('.opciones')){

             document.querySelectorAll(".opciones").forEach(el => {

                  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
 
                       console.log(el.id);

                  }

             })
    
          }

    })

Este es mi código, al tener 2 addEventListeners("click") no se ejecuta bien y tengo que esperar al segundo click para capturar el id, es decir sí lo captura pero en el segundo click que realizo y así pasa cada vez que cargo más listas.

Comment: Modifica la pregunta original, no agregues el código aquí, pulsa 'editar' en tu pregunta y agrega el contexto allí.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, salió perfectamente con tu aporte!  :)